# How do i solve this white-space problem in html css this is headeache

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Ok so im attaching a image testlink and code, the problem is that when i go in responsive size it starts to give me right side white-space, while in desktop size everything works fine. I'm confused now n how to fix this if i dont find any solution i have to build that thing again from scratch

the link where im testing this site, image & code(Html,CSS)
https://trendsavagetestsite.000webhostapp.com/index.php

[The White Spaced-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHjac.jpg)

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Luckiest_Guy';
    src: url(\trend\Fonts\LuckiestGuy-Regular.ttf);
}



*{ 
    font-family: "Luckiest_Guy";
}

html{
    
}

body{

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#396afc, #2948ff);
    
}

h1{
    font-size: 50px; 
    color: white;
}


.left{
    float: left;
    padding: 50px;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    padding: 50px;
}

h3.white{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="News\news.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="News\responsive-news.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Fonts\font.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <title>Trend Savage - News</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Heading Start -->
<h1 data-aos="fade-down" align="center">Welcome To The "Gaming News"</h1>
<!-- Heading End -->

<!-- Section Start -->
<div data-aos="fade-left" class="left">
<h3  data-aos="fade-up" class="white">"Pocket Gamers"</h3>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="480" data-height="320" data-theme="light" href="https://twitter.com/PocketGamer?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PocketGamer</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
</div>

<div data-aos="fade-right" class="right">
<h3  data-aos="fade-up" class="white">"Droid Gamers"</h3>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="480" data-height="320" href="https://twitter.com/DroidGamers?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by DroidGamers</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
</div>
<!-- Section End -->


<!-- Section Start -->
<div data-aos="fade-left" class="left">
<h3  data-aos="fade-up" class="white">"Touch Arcade"</h3>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="480" data-height="320" href="https://twitter.com/toucharcade?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by toucharcade</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
</div>

<div>
<div data-aos="fade-right" class="right">
<h3  data-aos="fade-up" class="white">"Game Zebo"</h3>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="480" data-height="320" href="https://twitter.com/gamezebo?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by gamezebo</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>   
</div>
<!-- Section End -->

<!-- Section Start -->
<div data-aos="fade-left" class="left">
<h3  data-aos="fade-up" class="white">"Mobile Mode Gaming"</h3>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="480" data-height="320" href="https://twitter.com/MobileModeGame?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by MobileModeGame</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
</div>

<div>
<div data-aos="fade-right" class="right">
<h3  data-aos="fade-up" class="white">"Pocket Tactics"</h3>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="480" data-height="320" href="https://twitter.com/PocketTactics?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PocketTactics</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    
</div>
<!-- Section End -->


<!-- Animate AOS initiate -->
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your site has a lot of code in the `body` that should be in the `head`

Comment: Probably some of your elements is causing the overflow. Inspect the code and try to remove/readd elements until you find the right one.

Comment: `.graph-cont { overflow: hidden; }` just like @pistevw said.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

Add overflow: hidden to .graph-cont

Comment: there isn't any class name .graph-cont in my css as you've mentioned and even if add this to its not working i tried overflow hidden directly to html and body but didn't worked

Comment: Please go through this image
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPe2L.png

Comment: ok it works in homepage but there is still a small line type white space but i dunno how to solve news page white space

Comment: add overflow: hidden to #footer in news page

Comment: i did upvote and apprroved but it seems its not registring my upvote i have low rep so i have to get more rep to make that upvote public

Comment: by the way i tried oveflow in footer it didn't worked

Comment: add this. It should work.

#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: Had you place this in css file?

#footer { overflow: hidden; }